# How to reference RecordTypeId via RelatedToId for EmailMessage

Tags: apex, trigger, emailmessage

can anyone please shed some light on how to reference the RecordTypeId of the record related to an EmailMessage via the RelatedToId field?

I would like to update the IsExternallyVisible field based on the Record Types of the related object.

Example trigger code:

```
trigger MakeEmailsPublic on EmailMessage (after insert) {

    for(EmailMessage em: Trigger.new){

        if(em.RelatedToId == '*RecTypeId_1*' || em.RelatedToId == '*RecTypeId_2*' ){

            em.IsExternallyVisible=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard [aggregate-query-update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) pattern, but with a twist: the relationship is polymorphic, so we need to do dynamic queries. Here's what the trigger would look like:

```
trigger MakeEmailsPublic on EmailMessage (after insert) {
    // Aggregate //
    Map<sObjectType, Set<id>> recordIdsByType = new Map<sObjectType, Set<Id>>();
    for(EmailMessage message: Trigger.new) {
        if(message.RelatedToId != null) {
            sObjectType key = message.RelatedToId.getSObjectType();
            Set<Id> recordIds = recordIdsByType.get(key);
            if(recordIds == null) {
                recordIdsByType.put(key, recordIds = new Set<Id>());
            }
            recordIds.add(message.RelatedToId);
        }
    }
    // Query //
    Map<Id, sObject> records = new Map<Id, sObject>();
    for(sOBjectType sType: recordIdsByType.keySet()) {
        if(sType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().containsKey('RecordTypeId')) {
            Set<Id> ids = recordIdsByType.get(sType);
            records.putAll(
                Database.query('SELECT RecordTypeId FROM '+sType+' WHERE Id = :ids')
            );
        }
    }
    // Update //
    for(EmailMessage message: Trigger.new) {
        sObject record = records.get(message.RelatedToId);
        if(record != null) {
            Id recordTypeId = (Id)record.get('RecordTypeId');
            if(recordTypeId == 'rectype1' || recordTypeId == 'rectype2') {
                message.IsExternallyVisible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```